# I am trying to downmix 5.1 flac to stereo using ffmpeg, but getting following error

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

here is the command i am trying to run, i am taking the MKV file which has 5.1 FLAC as audio, and mapping the audio to a FLAC file.

`%ffmpegpath% -i "%file%" -map 0:2 -vol 425 -af "pan=stereo|FL < 0.5C + 0.707L + 0.707Ls + 0.5LFE|FR < 0.5C + 0.707R + 0.707Rs + 0.5LFE" "stereo.flac"`

[here is the image of the error i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iJj2.png)

Comment: It's better to post text as text rather than a photo of it. The picture is an unsearchable resource & it cannot be read by people with sight issues using reader software.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am new this platform. Will keep in mind while making any post in the future.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `map` in this scenario.
According to the [ffmpeg documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation) you can simply downmix the audio channels with the `-ac <channels>` flag.

[image: 5.1 to stereo]

```
ffmpeg -i 6channels.wav -ac 2 stereo.wav
```

This command would convert a surround file to stereo.
You can of course use a `.mkv` file as input.

Your command would look like following:

```
%ffmpegpath% -i "%file%" -ac 2 stereo.flac
```

Comment: `-ac 2` will get the job done in a similar fashion, but i wanted to include the  LFE channel so i went with pan filter.  I used map to select one audio stream from file , as the file has multiple audio streams.

Comment: after reading pan documentation, i changed the letters to numbers, since it was also stated  you can use numbers [https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation#:~:text=You%20can%20also,c2%22%20output.wav]

Comment: the code somehow worked

Comment: `"%~dp0ffmpeg.exe" -i "%%G" -map 0:0 -map 0:2 -map 0:4 -map 0:3 -c:v copy -acodec flac -sample_fmt s16 -vol 425 -af "pan=stereo|FL < c2+c0+c4+0.5c3|FR < c2+c1+c5+0.5c3" "%~dp0%%G"`

Comment: The command you've used only takes audio from 4 channels, not from all 6.

Comment: i used c0(FL),c1(FR),c2(FC),c3(LFE),c4(BL),c5(BR) which  makes it 6